# Prove that a condition is false for a 3 elements subset of given subset of a group

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

On a math competition the students were solving n problems and every student solved three problems. For each pair of students there is at most one problem solved by both of them. Prove that if $s$ is a natural number, for which $s^2-s+1<2n$, there are $s$ problems for which no three of them were solved by a single student.

This is a Romanian olympiad question from 2004 and it proved a great challenge for my skills as I didn't make any significant progress so far.

I will be grateful for any solutions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not fully trust my own interpretation. Must it be proved that for every natural $s$ that satisfies $s^2-s+1<2n$ we can select a set $P$ of $s$ problems such that every subset of $P$ having cardinality $3$ contains a problem that was solved by $0$, $2$ or $3$ students? (i.e. no $3$ where solved by a single student).

Comment: For every 3 elements in s not all of them were solved by a single person

Comment: $s$ is a number (so does not contain elements in this context and that's why I created $P$ in my former comment). So you mean: at least one of the $3$ problems was solved by more or by less  than $1$ person?

Comment: Is this question (Romanian olympiad) on internet somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I mean that. No, there are not on Internet.